# Determine Issuer of EMV card

Tags: emv

What would be the best way to determine the issuer of a contactless EMV card. I am trying to determine if a card was issued by Amex, Visa or Mastercard. Is that information available via a USB EMV reader? I don't need to pull any other information from the card..

I'm assuming that it could be done by some python, or C++ code interacting with the card. I'm looking for a good jumping off point.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this info from the successful response of SELECT. Store the list of RIDs ( AID = RID + PIX ), and do SELECT one by one. On success, it will return status bytes 90 00, otherwise 6A 82( file not found ).

Comment: @adarash can you recommend a place with some sample code on how to do this or a good place to start?

Comment: You can download Book 1 from https://www.emvco.com/, and read section 11.3 SELECT Command-Response APDUs.  As to sample code, you can check in Github

Comment: @JasonSmall Have a look at [javaemvreader](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader)

Answer (score 0):

> The easiest option would be through **SELECT command** as mentioned
> before. The list of AID:
>
> https://www.eftlab.com/knowledge-base/211-emv-aid-rid-pix/

> The other option would be getting it from the **PAN**. You can define issuer
> based on first 6 digits or 8 digits of the PAN, which represents Issuer
> Identification Number (IIN)/Bank Identification Number(BIN).
>
> - 34, 37 - American Express
> - 4 - Visa
> - 51-55, 2221-2720 - MasterCard
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number#Issuer_identification_number_(IIN)
> You would have to send commands:
>
> 1. SELECT
> 2. GET PROCESSING OPTIONS
> 3. READ RECORD
>
> You would look for 5A - PAN and extract first digits.

Good tool that you can just use to read data from contactless EMV card is:
https://www.javacardos.com/tools/pyresman

You can create your own scripts or just proceed with some basic commands like a SELECT command.